# Class constructor Rectangle cannot be invoked without 'new' when importing from node_modules

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm using webpack for my project, and I'm importing a class from another package. However, when I extend this class, my code breaks with `Class constructor Rectangle cannot be invoked without 'new'`. If I copy the class definition from the node_module to my project it works however:

Other package:
This package is compiled by `tsc` with `"target": "ESNext"`.

```
export class Rectangle {
  // ...
}
```

My package: This package is compiled using webpack.

```
import { Rectangle } from 'other-package'

class A {
}
class B extends A {
}
class C extends Rectangle {
}

console.log(Rectangle)
// outputs: class Rectangle { ... }

console.log(A)
// outputs: ƒ A() { ... }

console.log(B)
// outputs: ƒ B() { ... }

console.log(C)
// outputs: ƒ C() { ... }

console.log(new Rectangle())
// outputs: Rectangle {top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0}

console.log(new A())
// outputs: A {}

console.log(new B())
// outputs: B {}

console.log(new C())
// Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Rectangle cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Comment: Got same random issue using Babel/typescript, I changed the tsconfig target to `es5` to make it work.